# Spring Security Plugin in Modular Applications

Tags: security, grails, architecture, spring-security

I'm starting a new, modular Grails application. I'm creating a domain plugin and of course need a User/Person domain.

Do I add the Spring Security Core plugin to domain, just to generate the its user domain? If so, do I also add the plugin to the main app. Or since the main app will use the domain plugin, will it inherit the Spring Security plugin?

In either case, is there anything I need to know or do differently than if I just had 1 application with the domain objects?

UPDATE

I added this to the buildconfig of my main app:

```
 plugins {
        . . .
        compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.1"
        . . .
    }   

grails.plugin.location.astdomain ="C:\\src\\astool\\astdomain"
```

Doing generate all in the main app didn't work. The domain I specified was not found. So I did a generate all in the domain plugin then moved the generated code into the main app. And even though the generated code has the same package as the domains, I still get a compile error saying the domain isn't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the section on [plugins](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/12.%20Plug-ins.html). I believe the distribution process has changed, however, as the [Release plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/release) seems to be becoming mainstream/the de-facto standard as of Grails 2.0.

It all depends on how you set it up. You should be able to add the spring security plugin to your plugin (which is essentially what you are doing in building a modular app, building a larger one as a series of plugins) and specify plugin dependencies, build orders, and the such that way.

With the right setup, you should be able to write your self-contained plugin, run a grails install-plugin on the main app referencing your plugin, and then use package resolution to get access to your plugin's domain classes in the main app's other classes.

Comment: As in, you want the main app's generate all script to pull in stuff from the plugin?  You'd have to either hack the app's generate all, or (more extensibly), write a Groovy script the plugin adds to the app that does this. I've never done this myself, but conceptually it's doable. You may want to look at the internals of the Spring Security Core plugin and see how S2-Quickstart works, as you'll essentially be doing something similar (maybe your script will take in parameters and then delegate the work to this other one)

Comment: Right, I have my domains in a domain plugin. But I'd like to be able to use scaffolding in the main app where the UI is going to be. But as the update says, that doesn't work. Nor does moving the generated code from the plugin to the main app.

Comment: Seems like you should install the Spring Security Core plugin in the domain plugin, run the S2-quickstart script to get the domain objects, then add a script that generates the controllers and views which can be called after installing your plugin in the main-app. 

It's also possible to have your plugin listen for and respond to certain events in the grails script process, for example the Spock plugin replaces the scaffolding of the default testing framework with Spock Specs. You may want to investigate how it does that.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it is essentially correct, if lacking a few details. But please see my own answer below. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the only problem was that I was including the plugin in the wrong place.

I had

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

  . . .

 plugins {
        . . .
        compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.1"
        . . .
    }   

  grails.plugin.location.astdomain ="C:\\src\\astool\\astdomain"


}
```

But it needs to be included outside grails.project.dependency.resolution = { . . }:

```
grails.plugin.location.'astdomain' ="../astdomain"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = { . . }
```

Notice too that I now have quotes around 'astdomain'. I'm not sure if that matters or not, but that how I saw someone else do this.

I'm also using the more general syntax: "../astdomin". But "C:..." does work too.